# Parse limits on orQueries

Tags: database, swift, parse-platform, subquery, xcode7

I am having a difficult time finding any documentation on Parse that answers the question I have. Here is a example of what I need.

```
let colorQuery1 = PFQuery(classname: "colors")
colorQuery1.whereKey("color", equalTo: red)

let colorQuery2 = PFQuery(classname: "colors")
colorQuery2.whereKey("color", equalTo: blue)

let colorQuery3 = PFQuery(classname: "colors")
colorQuery3.whereKey("color", equalTo: green)

let mainColorQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([colorQuery1, colorQuery2, colorQuery3])
mainColorQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects, error) -> Void in
// retrieve data
}
```

My problem is that I would like to retrieve approximately 15 items from the first two queries then approximately 150 items from the last query. This is not allowed because I cannot set limits on subQueries. I am also curious to know the default limits on the queries in this instance. In the example I provided, If there are a 1000 objects that are red will the mainQuery return only 100 or 1000 red objects and then the second and third queries be left blank? Help me find a way to limit the subQueries please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All queries have a default limit of 100 and a max limit of 1000.  OR'ing several that combine to > 1k results will generate a subset of 1k related (I think) to the order that the queries are passed.

But in your case, you can get much more control by replacing the OR'd queries with a single one that uses `containedIn` to specify the disjunction...

```
let colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
query.whereKey("color", containedIn: colors)
query.limit = 1000  // still the max
```

With this single query, you can add additional constraints to limit the result count, and/or execute it repeatedly with a skip to page through >1k results.

Comment: you have given me what I needed, but does this mean that each subquery will only return 100 objects regardless of how many are in the key?

Comment: 100, unless you set the limit higher, up to the max of 1k.